# How to get the last created table name from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, information-schema

I want to get the last created table name from a MySQL database using PHP.

I also used a query, but I cant to get any value. This is the query:

```
"select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'databse_name' order by create_time desc limit 1"
```

When I am using this I get value from local system but not get value from client's database.
What is the mistake in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your query works fine on your local machine, but in the live environment it doesn't?

Perhaps the MySQL user in the live environment has insufficient access? Try executing something like this in the live environment MySQL database:

```
GRANT SELECT ON information_schema.tables TO `user`@`localhost`
```

And replace `user` to the correct user name, also perhaps the `localhost` part if you connect to a database outside localhost.

Comment: you mean first execute this query after that excute the getting table name query ?

Comment: where should i excute this query?Directly in phpmyadmin or from my php page?

Comment: Thanks its working.now i get the last created table name from live environment

Comment: Great! To clarify you should only need to execute this query once, in phpmyadmin for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permiossion for the databases you want to access?

Try this please:

```
select create_time, table_name, table_schema 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema not in ('mysql')
and table_schema not like '%_schema'  
order by create_time desc
```

Do you get a result, if you don't get a result for the database you where referring to, then it must be the permissions.

Comment: when iam excuting this query at phpmyadmin directly i got the result

Comment: Is there the information you were looking for in the result? If so, just filter with table_schema = 'your_database', but this time copy the name out of your result. I was maybe a typo in your first attempts.